# UINavigationController: navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a `UINavigationController` in my storyBoard which is set to be my initialViewController. I set in Xcode `Navigator` as my class and created a class named Navigator.

There I implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` but the method [`navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621878-navigationcontroller?language=objc) is never called.

Do I need to do something else? Do I need to call `setDelegate`? because this didn't work for me.

Any advice?

Comment: did you implement the method inside the vc or the navigation subclass ??

Comment: I implemented it in my Navigator-class which is the class I set as 'class' in Xcode in my `UINavigationController`

Comment: in **awakeFromNib** set **self.delegate = self** ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan where do I get awakeFromNib?

Comment: @Sh_Khan please add your answer again. this solved my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
  self.delegate = self;
}
```

---

```
@interface Navigatior:UINavigationcontroller<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```